# How to map through nested objects of Laravel collection in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native

In my front-end I am trying to  map through nested objects which is coming from back-end Laravel collection:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Chips",
    "product_categories_id": 1,
    "category": {
      "id": 1,
      "category": "Chips",
      "brand": "Bombay Sweets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Book",
    "product_categories_id": 2,
    "category": {
      "id": 2,
      "category": "Shoe",
      "brand": "Nike",
    }
  }]
```

I want to display the product name and related category name from nested object. My approach is:

```
products.map((product)=>{
    console.log(product.name)
    product.category.map((category)=>(
        console.log(category.category)
    ))
})
```

which is not working at all. I spent huge amount of time to solve yet no luck.

the error it shows:

***ProductListContainer.js:58 Uncaught TypeError: item.category.map is not a function***

Comment: try this one, `console.log(product.category.category)` ?

Comment: saved !! but i needed to use object.entries

Answer (score 0):

`map` method works only with [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). You can use `product.category.category` to access the value.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved by this:

```
products.map((product) => {
    console.log(product.name)
    Object.entries(product.category).map(() => (
        console.log(product.category.category, product.category.brand)
    ))
})
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do a loop on product.category, all you need to do to display the category name is this:

```
{{product.category?.category}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Chips",
    "product_categories_id": 1,
    "category": {
      "id": 1,
      "category": "Chips",
      "brand": "Bombay Sweets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Book",
    "product_categories_id": 2,
    "category": {
      "id": 2,
      "category": "Shoe",
      "brand": "Nike",
    }
  }
];



arr.map((e) => {
  console.log(e.name);
  for (let x in e.category) {
    console.log(e.category[x]);
  }
});
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).